# Why does one-step TD strengthen only the last action of the sequence of actions that led to the high reward, while n-step TD the last n actions?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, comparison, temporal-difference-methods, sutton-barto, model-free-methods

In the caption of [figure 7.4 (p. 147)](https://incompleteideas.net/book/RLbook2020.pdf#page=169) of Sutton & Barto's book (2nd edition), it's written

> The one-step method strengthens only the last action of the sequence of actions that led to the high reward, whereas the n-step method strengthens the last n actions of the sequence, so that much more is learned from the one episode.

Why does one-step TD strengthen only the last action of the sequence of actions that led to the high reward, while n-step TD the last n actions?

Here's a screenshot of the figure.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a link if possible.

Comment: I've edited your post to include the link to the book and to clarify your question, but, please, next time, provide more details. In particular, you should explain **what** you don't understand, and what is your background in RL. Feel free to edit your post to add more details.